# Will a product-price history table greatly affect db performance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-postgresql

I have over a million products in a db. Each product's price fluctuates often. I plan on storing these price fluctuations in a "price history" table (product_id, price, validity_start_date, validity_end_date).

When a product is looked up, the user will see its price histroy via a js-generated chart from the json outputted from the db.

Am I going about this the right way?

(Using rails and postgresql).

Comment: It's kinda hard to tell without giving us any code. What you gave is a spec, not an implementation. Specs can't be wrong, only implementations -- although given, some problems are hard to solve.

Comment: the best way to handle this is to 'get a sense of the data'; specifically if you have 1 million records; implement with 1000 measure, 100,000 measure and then a million.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends.  In theory you don't need to have a big performance problem if you set things up with partial unique indexes for most recent parts (there are specific ways of doing so which are beyond the scope of this answer).

This gets really messy though when using ORM's and the like.  In general if you are going to be storing this sort of data I would highly recommend being willing to do one of two things:

1. You could abstract your storage behind updateable views (you'd have to be willing to write and maintain the update logic for the views though).
2. You could be willing to drop to SQL.

Millions of parts times thousands of historical prices though (over time) is going to be pretty annoying on an ORM without access to things like partial indexes and the like.